# Powershell UNC Path with credentials

Tags: windows, powershell

Background:
we created a script was watch our timestamp of the files and when it detect a file that last longer as 10 min in the hotfolder, the script automaticly restart the service.

Thats actually the powershell working powershell script:

```
#Variablen ausfüllen
$watchfolder = '\\dcsrv\public\Scanner-Eingang'#UNC Pfade funktionieren
$CurTimeStamp = Get-Date
$FileAge = 10 #in Minuten

#Er prüft die Zeit der Dokumente
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $watchfolder  | Where-Object{($_.LastWriteTime -le 
$CurTimeStamp.AddMinutes(-1 * $FileAge))}

#Für jedes Dokument
ForEach ($File in $Files) {
Write-Host " " $File " - " $File.LastWriteTime
## Damit wir der Dienst neugestartet
Restart-Service -Name Spooler

## Sobald er eine Datei gefunden hat stopt er
break
}
```

The service is running on a server out of the domain and need to reach the hotfolders. The hotfolders are on a domaincontroller with other credentials.
Now i need to connect in my powershell script with the right credentials, some examples i tried you can see here:

```
#Variablen ausfüllen
$watchfolder = '\\dcsrv\public\Scanner-Eingang'#UNC Pfade funktionieren
$CurTimeStamp = Get-Date
$username = 'user'
$password = '1234'
$FileAge = 10 #in Minuten

#Er prüft die Zeit der Dokumente
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $watchfolder $username $password | Where-Object{($_.LastWriteTime -le 
$CurTimeStamp.AddMinutes(-1 * $FileAge))}

#Für jedes Dokument
ForEach ($File in $Files) {
Write-Host " " $File " - " $File.LastWriteTime
## Damit wir der Dienst neugestartet
Restart-Service -Name Spooler

## Sobald er eine Datei gefunden hat stopt er
break
}
```

didnt worked then i tried something else

```
#Variablen ausfüllen
$watchfolder = '\\dcsrv\public\Scanner-Eingang'#UNC Pfade funktionieren
$CurTimeStamp = Get-Date
$FileAge = 10 #in Minuten

#Er prüft die Zeit der Dokumente
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $watchfolder /user:user password:1234 | Where-Object{($_.LastWriteTime - 
le $CurTimeStamp.AddMinutes(-1 * $FileAge))}

#Für jedes Dokument
ForEach ($File in $Files) {
Write-Host " " $File " - " $File.LastWriteTime
## Damit wir der Dienst neugestartet
Restart-Service -Name Spooler

## Sobald er eine Datei gefunden hat stopt er
break
}
```

also without success

Now i hope somebody can help me.

Thanks you!

Comment: [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.1) does not take Creentials. Take a look at the [cmdlets for managing PowerShell Drives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/managing-windows-powershell-drives?view=powershell-7.1). You can then use Get-ChildItem on the drive path.

Answer (score 4):

I think the main question is how do you authenticate to the remote domain, in order to watch the file share. `Get-ChildItem` doesn't have a `-credential` parameter.

You can try creating a mapped drive or path first, but you'll need to establish a credential object to use with the `New-PSDrive` command.

```
$Pwd  = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::New('UserName', $pwd)

New-PSDrive -Root '\\dcsrv\public\Scanner-Eingang' -PSProvider FileSystem -Name "ShareToMonitor" -Credential $Cred
...
```

*Note* For Powershell 4.0, change:

```
$Cred = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::New('UserName', $pwd)
```

to:

```
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential('UserName',$Pwd)
```

You can read about New-PSDrive [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive?view=powershell-5.1#parameters).

However, it's usually a bad idea to write a password directly into a script.  You can store it securely in a file

There are many guides and/or blog articles on the Internet to help with that.  Here's the first [Google result](https://www.pdq.com/blog/secure-password-with-powershell-encrypting-credentials-part-1/).  Once you establish the secure file you'll have to add code to the script to retrieve it.  Then use it to create the credential object as demonstrated above.

Note: The file can only be decoded on the computer and under the account from which it was created.